# Does Nuget store all versions of a package?

Tags: nuget

I have heard that the nuget server never deletes a version of a packages. Is that true?

I am working on a solution that stores all packages in subversion and I want to stop that practices. So I need some ammunition, so I can convince the owner of the code to only store the packages fil.

I know that you can setup a private nuget server but if packages are never deleted then there is no need for it, except downtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feed at https://www.nuget.org/ does not necessarily store all versions of a certain library, just those that have been uploaded.

Once uploaded, the packages are never deleted under normal circumstances. There are some exceptions of course, e.g. [for dispute resolution](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/dispute-resolution).